# Can "lstrip" and "rstrip" be used at the same time in git for-each-ref?

Tags: git

I have a pull request reference name like this one

```
refs/remotes/origin/pull-requests/283/from
```

I want to use strip out 3 paths from left and 1 from the right and the final output desired is `pull-requests/283`.

Can `lstrip` and `rstrip` be used at the same time?

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:lstrip=-3;rstrip=-1)' refs/remotes/origin/pull-requests/
```

is giving me the following error. Is it possible to do?

```
fatal: Integer value expected refname:lstrip=-3;rstrip=-1
```

Comment: Shouldn't `;` be `:` ?

Comment: It is the same result for `;` and `:`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no": the `%(field:modifier)` syntax only allows for one modifier.  It would be reasonable to ask for it to allow multiple modifiers separated by colons or semicolons, as you're trying to do, but it currently doesn't do that.

(Consider piping the `for-each-ref` output through a more capable program.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am doing that and my way of doing it is like this

```
#!/bin/sh
fmt='r=%(refname:lstrip=-3);echo "$r" | sed -e "s/\/from//"'
eval=$(git for-each-ref --shell --format="$fmt"  --sort=-authordate --count=10 refs/remotes/origin/pull-requests)
eval "$eval"
```

Comment: Avoid `eval` if you can. You probably can: consider `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' | awk -F/ '{...}'` where the awk script prints the desired fields. Awk is good at this kind of thing.

Comment: Sure I was getting that example from here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref